# Writing a summation formula using variables from multiple observations

Tags: r, distance

I am trying to create a new variable for each observation using the following formula:

Index = ∑(BAj / DISTANCEij)

where:
j = focal observation; i= other observation

Basically, I'm taking the focal individual (i) and finding the euclidean distance between it and another point and dividing the other points BA by that distance. Do that for all the other points and then sum them all and repeat all of this for each point.

Here is some sample data:

```
ID <- 1:4
BA <- c(3, 5, 6, 9)
x <- c(0, 2, 3, 7)
y <- c(1, 3, 4, 9)
df <- data.frame(ID, BA, x, y)
print(df)

  ID BA x y
1  1  3 0 1
2  2  5 2 3
3  3  6 3 4
4  4  9 7 9
```

Currently, I've extracted out vectors and created a formula to calculate part of the formula shown here:

```
vec1 <- df[1, ]
vec2 <- df[2, ]

dist <- function(vec1, vec2) vec1$BA/sqrt((vec2$x - vec1$x)^2 + 
                                                (vec2$y - vec1$y)^2)
```

My question is how do I repeat this with the x and y values for vec2 changing for each new other point with vec1 remaining the same and then sum them all together?

Comment: is the vec1, vec2, fixed

Comment: Yes they are fixed

Comment: If they are fixed, not clear how the x and y values are changing for vec2.

Comment: Perhaps you want `combn(df$ID, 2, FUN = function(i) dist(df[df$ID == i[1],], df[df$ID == i[2],]))`

Comment: I'm sorry I may be misunderstanding what you are asking. I am not very R savvy. So I'm not sure in vec1 and vec2 are necessary. Im just trying to calculate the summation formula mentioned at the beginning. That was the only idea I had.

Comment: that is okay.  The code I showed uses your dist function and gives the output.  If you can check whether that is the expected output, it would be great

Comment: Ok so the first three values in the output are correct, but I'm looking to just have those three values summed together for that particular point.

Comment: Not clear why you are taking 3 values each for summing

Comment: Ok, let me back up and explain what I'm trying to do. Take a point, A, for A I am trying to get an index value that will become a new variable. To get the value for A we go to the next point, B, and take it's BA variable and divide by the distance between A and B. You do this again with A and the next point until you have done it with all the points. You then add them all together to get the index value for A. You would then repeat with B and so on.

Comment: Try the solution I posted

Answer (score 1):

We may loop over the row sequence, extract the data and apply the `dist` function

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>% 
  mutate(dist_out = map_dbl(row_number(), ~ {
        othr <- cur_data()[-.x,]
        cur <- cur_data()[.x, ]
     sum(dist(cur, othr))
  }))
```

-output

```
 ID BA x y dist_out
1  1  3 0 1 2.049983
2  2  5 2 3 5.943485
3  3  6 3 4 6.593897
4  4  9 7 9 3.404545
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you so much! A have a couple other things if you don't mind. One is there a way to only include those points that have a distance less than say 5 from the focal individual? Also could you give me a quick explanation as to how that code works so I can know for next time? I'm eager to learn how these things work so I don't have to keep asking for help. Again thank you!

Comment: If you need to filter out do `%>% filter(dist_out <=5)` at the end

Comment: @ashell23 Regarding the code, `row_number()` gets the row sequence index, which we loop with `map`, inside the loop, extract the data for the current row ('cur') and the others (`-.x` - returns all rows other than the looped when we subset), apply the `dist` on the 'cur' and 'othr' data and get the `sum` of the vvalues..  `_dbl` returns the output numeric

Answer (score 1):

Here are two base R ways.

### 1. `for` loop

```r
ID <- 1:4
BA <- c(3, 5, 6, 9)
x <- c(0, 2, 3, 7)
y <- c(1, 3, 4, 9)
df <- data.frame(ID, BA, x, y)

n <- nrow(df)
d <- dist(df[c("x", "y")], upper = TRUE)
d <- as.matrix(d)
Index <- numeric(n)
for(j in seq_len(n)) {
  d_j <- d[-j, j, drop = TRUE]
  Index[j] <- sum(df$BA[j]/d_j)
}
Index
#> [1] 2.049983 5.943485 6.593897 3.404545
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

### 2. `sapply` loop

```r
Index <- sapply(seq_len(n), \(j) sum(df$BA[j]/d[-j, j, drop = TRUE]))
Index
#> [1] 2.049983 5.943485 6.593897 3.404545
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>